# expressjs support for method delete and put without the methodoverride

Tags: forms, node.js, express

How do i get expressjs to use the delete and put methods for form?

```
<form method="DELETE" action="">
```

Using the above is sending a GET request in latest stable version of chrome. Is this supposed to be a browser issue?

Is there a better way to override this without having a special input field for supporting these?

Comment: delete and put generally only work through XMLHttpRequests, not through regular form submissions like you're trying to do. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers

Comment: expressjs and nodejs use REST architecture. he needs to use PUT and/or DELETE

Comment: For express 4 - you will find the answer here.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019489/node-js-express-4-x-method-override-not-handling-put-request?answertab=votes#answer-24020025][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019489/node-js-express-4-x-method-override-not-handling-put-request?answertab=votes#answer-24020025

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You just need to set the form to post, then create a hidden field like

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
```

And set the configuration, according to the express version you are using. Then the form method will be overridden by the value of that hidden field.

The latest version of [express.js](/questions/tagged/express.js) will require you to install the [method-override](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override) package, then configure your app like this:

```
var methodOverride = require('method-override')
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
```

Old versions might use:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

An even older usage was:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

Comment: It is possible to use `app.use(express.urlencoded());` and `app.use(express.methodOverride());`

`bodyParser` adds support for file uploading which may not be desireable. [Express docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#bodyParser) has more details.

Comment: actually express.bodyParser() is deprecated in versions 3.4 of Express and 2.9 of Connect. There is security issues on the use of express.bodyParser() explained here

Comment: I think this is the [article](http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html) @ErnestConill is referring to:

Comment: I'm trying first way, but its not working, by default POST method is calling. This is my code, https://kopy.io/FCPAu

Answer (score 2):

actually express.bodyParser() is deprecated in versions 3.4 of Express and 2.9 of Connect.
There is security issues on the use of express.bodyParser() [explained here](http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html)