# Express cannot PUT/DELETE method. What is going wrong?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

Ok So I have a simple node.js / express.js / mongodb app set up here with my config as follows.

```
var express = require('express'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');
    http = require('http');

var app = express();

    app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    //middleware stack
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
});

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/hello");
```

The problem lies when I try to make PUT or DELETE requests. My form is this simple

```html
<form method="POST" action="/users/#{user.name}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
</form>
```

Now my router catches the route with the express .put() method

```js
app.put('/users/:name', function(req, res) {

    var b = req.body;

    Users.update(
        { name: req.user.name },
        { name: b.name, age: b.age, email: b.email },
        function(err) {
            res.redirect('/users/'+b.name);
        });
})
```

When I make the request I simply get a "Cannot PUT" or "Cannot DELETE" error.

I have tried to make this same request via chomes RESTful client with the same result.

I have read a topic witch has the same problem as me although following the comments the answers did not solve my problem.

Questions I have looked into
[expressjs support for method delete and put without the methodoverride](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859287/expressjs-support-for-method-delete-and-put-without-the-methodoverride)

[Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)

Along with a few others.
I have also referenced the express.js and mongo documentation several times.
I just cant think what could be going wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm working on the same thing, and can't seem to get the DELETE to go thru.

Comment: What did you end up doing about this? I'm having the same problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603372/express-rest-server-losing-payload-from-ember-data-put

Comment: @Mike the solution I accepted is below.

Comment: @DanielTate Since you did the "Rollback to Revision 2 - Edit approval overridden by post owner": from the answers, it seems clear that you ask for the "Cannot PUT ..." or "Cannot DELETE ..." error which should be quoted as an error then, with the capital C in "Cannot" and not as if cannot could be put there just in "bad English". The header should be something like `Express "Cannot PUT ..." / "Cannot DELETE ..." error: How to get the PUT / DELETE method working in Express?`

Comment: @questionto42 it was a copy + paste. No need to update anything.

Comment: @DanielTate OK then the message popped up like this, I see. I could not expect this when in the question body, you mention "Cannot PUT" or "Cannot DELETE" and I only know the latter error message ("Cannot PUT /mytable"). You should put it in quotations then.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**

As Jonathan Lonowski pointed out `PUT` can also be used, so you can ignore my old answer.
Getting `Cannot PUT` or `Cannot POST` errors, means your callback is not executing successfully. My guess is that `Users.update` is failing, which is why it cannot POST or PUT. Can you check it.

**Old answer**

Try changing this line

```
app.put('/users/:name', function(req, res) {
```

to

```
app.post('/users/:name', function(req, res) {
```

since you are trying to submit the form

Comment: HTML form has only two valid methods GET and POST.

Comment: @user568109 hi, can you please update your answer? it is google #1 for "express put not working", but it doesn't answer the question. i faced the same problem and it took 1 hour to find the answer : when we redirect in `put` method, it will redirect to another put. so we get `Cannot PUT` error. see my answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57577635/4718434

Comment: This answer saved relieved me after 3 days of deep searching about the DELETE request and over-ride package. Thanks @user568109.

Comment: This answer saved relieved me after 3 days of deep searching about the DELETE request and over-ride package. Thanks @user568109.

Answer (score 3):

Is the `<form>` you listed in a view or a `static` file under `__dirname + "/public"`?

Within a static file, the `#{user.name}` probably isn't being replaced with the `user`'s `name` and will be treated as a [URL Fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

The `<form>` will actually submit to `/users/` rather than `/users/:name` since that's the `path`:

```
console.log(url.parse('/users/#{user.name}'));

{ hash: '#{user.name}',
  pathname: '/users/',
  path: '/users/',
  href: '/users/#{user.name}' }
```

The `<form>` should be generated from a view if it isn't since the `action` needs to be dynamic and data-driven. With Jade and assuming `user` is a member of `locals`, that would be:

```
form(method='POST', action='/users/' + user.name)
  input(type='hidden', name='_method', value='PUT')
```

Comment: I am using a jade template, I apologize but this is psudo code the name is being replaced as I see it in the response but it would be for example "Cannot PUT USERNAME"

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is strange magic at work, your form makes a POST request, not a PUT. If you want to PUT, I would suggest using the [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function with a `type: 'PUT'` parameter, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153917/how-to-send-a-put-delete-request-in-jquery#answer-2153931), from a form handler, see [`jQuery.submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/). Don't forget to `return false` so that the form doesn't submit twice.

Comment: In all of the express documentation I have read they imply that you can achieve a PUT request with the hidden field in my form.

Comment: Yep, that sounds like magic :) Could you provide a reference?

Comment: [this](http://clientexpressjs.com/guide) is a copy from the documentation. I am wondering if the correct method to PUT has changed since this version. Unfortunatly there is no version listed on that tutorial.
I have been watching some tutorials on nettutsplus and they use this same method although in their documentation they state they are using version 3.0 of express where I am using 3.1.

Comment: That is a neat trick, sometimes the only reason I use jQuery is to get access to the whole HTTP vocabulary. I would certainly not expect a site-breaking change like this in a minor version number update. The only thing I can think of is to try another method on the client, to eliminate the possibility that there is a server side problem. I agree that your method is much more elegant however, and it might be worth it to keep using Express 3.0 for that feature alone (if it actually was removed).

Comment: one remark: Do not return false. use event.preventDefault at the beginning of the submithandler.

Answer (score 1):

If your using method override, make sure you have declared it before you use your routes. That was the problem I was having.

Answer (score 0):

**app.post("/movies/:id")** is one solution.
If you still want to use **app.put("/movies/:id")** then try this:

1. Install method-ovveride from npm.
2. Require it in your app.js file.
3. Open the form from where you wanna invoke PUT request
4. make sure your form has the following attributes:

   **action="/movies/<%= movies._id %>?_method=PUT "   method="POST" >**

These two solutions worked for me. If you are following REST, then use the method-ovveride else app.post() will also do the trick

Comment: I thought it worth mentioning that <%= %> is ejs. So it wouldn't work for OP because he is using jade.

Answer (score 0):

Change `res.redirect('path')` to `res.redirect(303, 'path')`

**In `Put` and `Delete`, if you want to redirect to `get` address, you should pass 303 as first parameter.** ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33215327/4718434))

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to use **cors** middleware for you **PUT,PATCH and DELETE** requests like this in your **app.js** file like this:

first install the **cors** package via npm :

`npm i cors`

then add the following code to your app.js:

```
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
```