# Node.js - Express 4.x - method-override not handling PUT request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am attempting to have the server handle a PUT request. But to no avail. The client keeps receiving "Cannot POST /" message after submitting the form.  **I am using Express 4.x.**

Note that if I change "put" to "post" in my route, the request gets handled just fine...

How can I have my server handle the 'PUT' request?

**SERVER:**

```
var express         = require("express");
var bodyParser      = require("body-parser");
var methodOverride  = require("method-override");

var app             = express();

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(methodOverride());


app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("index.ejs");
    console.log("GET received.");
});
app.put("/",function(req,res){
    console.log("PUT received: " + req.body.userName + " - " + req.body.password);
});

app.listen(1337);
console.log("Listening on 1337.");
```

**CLIENT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/" method="post">
            First
            <input type="text" name="first">
            Last
            <input type="text" name="last">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A simpler way could be [override using a query value](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override#override-using-a-query-value):

```
var methodOverride = require('method-override')

// override with POST having ?_method=PUT
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))
```

Example call with query override using HTML :

```
<form method="POST" action="/resource?_method=PUT">
  <button type="submit">Put resource</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Cheers.This fixes the issue with the minimum amount of fuss so should be considered the best answer.

Answer (score 13):

As of [method-override v2.0.0](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override) (release 2014-06-01), the default behaviour of the middleware does not check the POST body for a `_method` field; it only checks the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header.

In order for method-override to operate as it did in previous versions, you need to provide a custom function to `methodOverride`, which is detailed on [the project page](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override):

> #### custom logic
>
> You can implement any kind of custom logic with a function for the `getter`. The following implements the logic for looking in `req.body` that was in `method-override` 1:
>
> ```
> var bodyParser     = require('body-parser')
>
> var connect        = require('connect')
> var methodOverride = require('method-override')
>
> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
> app.use(methodOverride(function(req, res){
>   if (req.body && typeof req.body === 'object' && '_method' in req.body) {
>     // look in urlencoded POST bodies and delete it
>     var method = req.body._method
>     delete req.body._method
>     return method
>   }
> }))
> ```

Comment: This is unnecessary. The answer below is correct as you can read [here](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override#override-using-a-query-value) in the `method-override` documentation. The answer below is already showing this. It should be the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

We could also use a simple middleware to handle `x-http-method-override`

```
     var router = express.Router();

     /**
     * Middleware that detects a HTTP method tunneled,
     * inside the header of another HTTP method. Detects
     * and routs to the method mentioned in the header.
     */

    router.use((req,resp,next)=>{
        if(req.headers['x-http-method-override']){
            req.method = req.headers['x-http-method-override'];
        }
        next();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I just started building my first `express` project and the following code works. Coming from Laravel, I wanted my routes to check for the presence of `_method` field and determine the appropriate route. So I created a middleware to do this.

```
import { RequestHandler } from "express";

// Updates the request method if there is a 
// "_method" field present in the request query or
// request body.
const methodOverride: RequestHandler = function (req, res, next) {

    // Set the request method to the "_method" value in query
    // or the request body. Perform a validation before setting the
    // request method.
    req.method = req.query._method || req.body._method || req.method;

    // Carry forward the request to next middleware
    return next();
};

export default methodOverride;
```

Use this middleware before any route related middlewares. And now, my forms can look like this

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="first">
    <input type="text" name="last">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The `router.put('/', handler)` will be executed instead of `router.post('/', handler)`

Comment: i'am trying this, but its not working in form-data, only works in x-www-form-urlencoded, any solution?

Comment: I think you have to add a middleware to parse x-www-form-urlencoded inputs. Once that's added, the data will be there in request body/query.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose how to override:

```
// override with different headers; last one takes precedence

app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method'))          // Microsoft
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')) // Google/GData
app.use(methodOverride('X-Method-Override'))      // IBM
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way could be override using a query value:
http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/method-override.html

[image]